# Extensions with radicals such that $F=K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq ... \subseteq K_m=K$ where every $[K_i:K_{i-1}]$ is a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F=F_0\subseteq F_1\subseteq ... \subseteq F_m=K$ be extensions with radicals, show that they exist extensions with radicals such that $F=K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq ... \subseteq K_m=K$ where every $[K_i:K_{i-1}]$ is a prime number.

---

My first attempt was to use somehow solvable groups, but that doesn't work because if $[K_i:K_{i-1}]$ is cyclic doesn't mean it's of a prime order.

My second attempt was to show somehow that radical extensions can be manipulated so that the extension to always be $2$ and so prime.

Can someone give me a hint how to start, or the basic idea ?

Comment: You can apply induction, and then factor $[F_i , F_{i-1}]$ into primes.

Comment: If you can show $[K_i:K_{i-1}]$ is a cyclic extension, then it is Galois, you can use the property of its Galois group with respect to group theory to see what you can get.